# NSFetchRequests returns 0 results when it should return 1

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to perform a fetch on core data after i insert an entity, and I get 0 results.
I have a Person Entity.And i built a fetch Request in the DataModule GUI with the predicate:

> name == "PERSONNAME"

Just before searching for the name i insert and save it first. and i know that works because i display the names in a table and the coredata is saved after i close and open the application again.

Here is the code i coded for the fetch.
Please help me understand why am i getting 0 results

```
-(Person *)findPersonByName:(NSString *)name{
    NSLog(@"looking for person with name: %@",name);
    NSDictionary *subs = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:name forKey:@"PERSONNAME"];
    NSAssert(self.managedObjectModel, @"anything wrong with managedObjectModel");//no
    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [self.managedObjectModel fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"getPersonByName" substitutionVariables:subs];
    NSAssert(fetch, @"anything wrong with fetch?");//no
    NSLog(@"fetch: %@",fetch);
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    NSLog(@"fetch request getQuestionsByParent: %u found (sub variables:%@, results:%@)", [result count], subs, result);
    if (result == nil){
        // Deal with error...
    }
    else if([result count]>0){
        for (Person *person in result) {
            NSLog(@"search result: %@",person.name);
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Please help resolve the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your predicate template:

```
name == "PERSONNAME"
```

should be:

```
name == $PERSONNAME
```

Comment: when i create the predicate in the xcdatamodel with :
name == "$PERSONNAME"

its still dosent work, I cant find the way to loose the "" around the PERSONNAME

Comment: I did now realize that i needed to edit it in the "expression mode" after i created the predicate. 
So what i did was copy the predicate and then edit again and select expression from the dropdown then pasted and changed to :
name == $PERSONNAME

Thanks Rob.